# Calculate $\int_\gamma\omega$, parameterization on $R^2 - 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Ok guys, I'm a bit confused on what the difference between $R^2 - 0$ and $R^2$ is, and the parameterization is just replacing x,y,dx,and dy with the components of $\gamma(t)$ and then taking the integral over t right? Anyway here is the question below:

Let $\gamma(t) = (cos(t),sin(t)) $ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$ be the standard parameterization of the unit circle in $R^2$. If $$\omega = \frac{(x-y)dx+(x+y)dy}{x^2+y^2}$$

on $R^2 - 0$, calculate $\int_\gamma \omega$. Then explain why your answer implies that there is no function $f:R^2 -0 \rightarrow R$ with $df = \omega$

Anyway, guys I appericated any hints, helps or soluitions on this problem.

Comment: I got $2*\pi$ for the integral btw... im not sure how to answer part 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point with $\mathbb{R}^2$ vs $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus 0$ is that your $1$-form is undefined at the origin (because of the $x^2+y^2$ in the denominator).

To compute $\int_\gamma \omega$ you can indeed proceed as ususal, as long as the curve $\gamma$ avoids the origin, and $2\pi$ is the correct answer.

For the second part, assume that $df = \omega$, then
$$\int_\gamma \omega = \int_{\gamma} df = f(\gamma(2\pi)) - f(\gamma(0)) = 0.$$
Does this computation contradict your first one? What can you conclude?

Comment: SInce it equals 0 and gamma is on $R^2\0$ it is not part of the set and therefore $$df \ne \omega$$